# ViewPager and FragmentActiviy instead of Fragment

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I had a simple app and I now changing it to be more professional...
Now I want all part of my app get into a `ViewPager` instead of hiding under buttons, a part of my app is a FileManager that extended `Activty`, I Changed that to extends `FragmentActivty` to work with `ViewPager` with no success after all.

My question is: is it possible to use other kind of Fragments instead of `Fragment` for `ViewPager` at all?

should I code my FileManager from Scratch!!!??? 
Is there any Alternative?

EDIT : I Want to create something almost like this [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.youmi.filemaster)

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0: 
            return FragmentClass.newInstance(0, "Page # 1");
        case 1: 
            return FragmentClass.newInstance(1, "Page # 2");
        case 2: 
            return FileDialog.newInstance(2, "FileManager");
//Here is my problam, that says "Type mismatch: cannot convert from FileDialog to Fragment"
//It wants Fragment type
            default:
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FragmentActivity is not a Fragment, it's a special Activity in the support libraries which allows you to use Fragments in older versions of Android. Unfortunately you cannot put a FragmentActivity in a ViewPager. You must classes derived from the Fragment class in the support library if you intend to use the ViewPager because the ViewPager only exists in the support library.

To clarify on Fragments, there are two different Fragment superclasses you'll encounter (both of which are called Fragment). The difference is that one is from the normal Android libraries and the other is from the support libraries. You need Fragments derived from the Fragment superclass in the support libraries (android.support.v4.app.Fragment) if you want to use them with the ViewPager.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any alternative for `ViewPager`? Lots of apps have this functionality, for instance the stock JellyBean Contacts app or the app I mentioned in my question. I just want the ability to slide app section like the way `ViewPager` provides. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

A Fragment itself is a superclass, and can be utilized in different ways.

[Take a look at the developer docs on Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) for their implementation, and best practices in terms of use. Unless you're looking for a very specific library to your application, you shouldn't need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I already read that docs. I edited my question.   Is it possible to use other kind of Fragments instead of Fragment for ViewPager at all? I Meant in my providing code. thanks for your time